# How to change side menu in ionic for a loggedin user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to change content of side menu when a user is logged in.

**Example 1 - user not logged in**:

This side menu is shown when a user isn't logged in.

[image]

**Example 2 - user is logged in**:

As you can see, there are a couple of extra menu items. These are only shown when a user is logged in.

[image]

in my controller:

```
$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/consommateurs/'+$localStorage.idconsommateur, { params: { "idconsommateur":$localStorage.idconsommateur, fields: "nom,prenom",format:"json"} }).then(function(result) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
                $scope.prenomconsommateurConnect=result.data.prenom;
```

in the view :

```
 <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable" >
                <h1 class="title" ng-hide="!prenomconsommateurConnect" ng-controller="accueilController">Bonjour Hello {{prenomconsommateurConnect}}</h1>
                <h1 class="title" ng-hide="prenomconsommateurConnect" ng-controller="accueilController">Bonjour Hello link</h1>

                </ion-header-bar>
```

but i found always this result "bonjour hello link" what can i do please??

What can I do? Should I use `ng-if`, `ng-show` or `ng-hide`?
Or is there another/better solution for this case?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ng-if is load element only if expression is true and ng-show is used to hide and unhide element based on expression.

Comment: I would use `ng-if`. I had a login page where when the user logged in then I need to hide the login/register button else show them.

Comment: If you use ui-router you can define (in your app.config using $stateProvider) a state (abstract) with menu1 and another state with menu2

Comment: look please i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put ng-if OR ng-show and ng-hide..
i have used  ng-if..!

in menu controller:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$http) {

$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/elodieService/consommateurs/'+$localStorage.idconsommateur, {
  params: { "idconsommateur":$localStorage.idconsommateur, fields: "nom,prenom",format:"json"} })
  .then(function(result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
    if(result.data.prenom) {
      $scope.prenomconsommateurConnect = result.data.prenom;
    }else{
      $scope.prenomconsommateurConnect = "";
    }
});

$scope.$watch(function () {
  return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
}, function (value) {
  console.log("value " + value);
  $scope.getMenuProfile();
});

$scope.getMenuProfile = function () {
  if($scope.prenomconsommateurConnect === "" ){
    $scope.isLogin =false ;
  }else{
    $scope.isLogin =true ;
  }
};
}
```

menu.html

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 ng-if="!isLogin" class="title">Login plz</h1>
  <h1 ng-if="isLogin"  class="title">U are Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
```

hope this helped you.

Comment: always i have Login plz :( what can i do ?

Comment: if u are login..already..just get local stored info..and use instead of calling API..

Comment: nothing ,always this result (login plz) ,please help me more

Comment: just put console every point...comment here..wht is the value in result.data.prenom, console in  if(result.data.prenom) {}else{} find wht value is getting set..!?comment me back..!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98966/discussion-between-the-mahasagar-and-rim-bejaoui).