# How to add and hide item in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, residemenu

i have a side-menu and i want to change the item of this side

eg: if user is connect ==> item my account is show

but if user is not connect ==>item my account  is hide

in my controller:

```
facebookExample.controller("accueilController", function($scope, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location,$ionicPopup,$state,$http) {

$scope.connect=true;
$localStorage.connect=true;
```

in the index.html :

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="accueilController" >
    <ion-item class="item" nav-clear menu-close href="#/login" ng-show="connect=='true'">
                             <i class="fa fa-user" style="padding-right: 190px;"></i> <div style="padding-left: 25px;padding-top: 5px;">My account  </div>                   
                            </ion-item>
```

i found nothing ,what can i do ,i use ng-if or ng-how and how ??

help me please

Comment: did u tried..ur last question's [ans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34459188/4302328)..!and [this](http://codepen.io/sagarchaudhari/pen/OMRjrz?editors=001)..!its same..kind!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that check in the ng-show

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="accueilController" >
<ion-item class="item" nav-clear menu-close href="#/login" ng-show="connect">
  <i class="fa fa-user" style="padding-right: 190px;"></i>
  <div style="padding-left: 25px;padding-top: 5px;">My account</div>                   
</ion-item>
```

Comment: for your code i show item of my account but if connect =false ,i always show

Comment: Check this: http://jsbin.com/lasadeg/edit?html,js,output The problem might be in other part of the code.