# rerender view for a separated controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a user system using ionic framework (angularjs). I'm facing issue rerendering the sidebar after user has logged in. For example the menu should hide login link like below

```
<ion-item menu-close ng-show="!loggedIn" href="#/app/login">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-show="loggedIn" href="#/app/profile">
          Profile
        </ion-item>
```

How to do set loggedIn to true? because I have my login function in another controller. Should I watch `$scope.loggedIn` in this case?

I can also hard refresh but it just doesn't update, I tried $location.reload, $state.go({reload:true}) and window.location = 'something', the sidebar doesn't get updated.

Comment: You can share your login status between controllers simply by storing it as 'global' variable in some service/factory.

Comment: @MateuszDryzek I used $rootscope but how to rerender or refresh the view of the sidebar?

Comment: you should bind the loggedIn to your login status. i.e. in sidebar controller, scope.loggedIn = $rootScope.userLoggedIn;. But I'd suggest using a service rather than pollute the rootScope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34459188/4302328